# Android - Fastest way to search data in SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have an image processing app. My app stores the already processed images in a database. Every time the user opens the app, the app starts to check the database to see what photos have already been processed. With my code this process is taking around 10-20 seconds, which for my needs is a lot of time.
The database only has one column, the path of the image. I take the full image list from the phone and then search every item of the list in the database.

My code is as follows:

```
public static ArrayList<String> getAlreadyProcessedPhotos(Context context, ArrayList<String> photos, SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    ArrayList<String> notAlreadyProcessedPhotos = new ArrayList<>();

    for(String path : photos)
    {
        File imgFile = new File(path);

        if (!Utils.isAlreadyProcessed(context, imgFile, db))
        {
            notAlreadyProcessedPhotos.add(path);
        }
    }

    return notAlreadyProcessedPhotos;
}

public static boolean isAlreadyProcessed(Context context, File imgFile, SQLiteDatabase photosDb) {
    if(photosDb == null || !photosDb.isOpen())
        photosDb = new DatabaseHelper(context).getReadableDatabase();

    String searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.PATH_COLUMN + "=?";

    Cursor cursor = photosDb.rawQuery(searchQuery, new String[] {imgFile.getAbsolutePath()});
    boolean result = cursor.moveToFirst();
    cursor.close();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: be much quicker to say in the `searchQuery`, instead of using `*`, do it this way, `SELECT TOP 1 ...`

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a database? Might it not be faster to just search a folder for the name? Not an expert on either, but I've used both successfully. Since you're using `getAbsolutePath()` anyway, why not then just see if file `exists()`? (This is sort of knee-jerk reaction; take with grain of salt.)

Comment: also to chime in @DSlomer64 's comment, what if there's far too many images, it would take time to process them all, I agree, also, checking if file exists would be the right route to take. You can dismiss my earlier comment.

Comment: No, I need the database, becuase my app overwrites the original photo, so the photo always exists (sometimes not processed and others processed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each file that you want to check you are executing a separate sqlite query. No wonder it's slow! If there are 100 files you will need to do a 100 queries. But this can really be done with one simple query. You just need to combine your two methods into 1

```
public static ArrayList<String> getAlreadyProcessedPhotos(Context context, ArrayList<String> photos, SQLiteDatabase db)
{
   ArrayList<String> notAlreadyProcessedPhotos = new ArrayList<>();
   ArrayList<String> preProc = new ArrayList()

   for (String item: photos) {
       preProc.add("'" + item + "'");
   } 
   String inClause = TextUtils.join(",", preProc);

   String searchQuery = "SELECT " + DatabaseHelper.PATH_COLUMN + "FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.PATH_COLUMN + "NOT IN (" +inClause + ")";
   Cursor cursor = photosDb.rawQuery(searchQuery);

   while(cursor.moveToNext()) 
   {
        notAlreadyProcessedPhotos.add(cursor.getString(0);
   }

   return notAlreadyProcessedPhotos;
}
```

This is one loop, one query. I don't know where your photos array list comes from but I get the feeling there is room for further optimization there as well.

Comment: I am agree with this. And i think you should add an index to your column to increase the search.

Comment: @CL I think you missed this bit: String inClause = TextUtils.join(",", photos);

Comment: This results in a single string: `... path IN ('x,y,z') ...`.

Comment: In SQL, quotes in strings are escaped by doubling them (`'it''s a quote'`). In Java, a character would be written as `'\''`.

Comment: Well spotted!! Updated the answer again!

Comment: Thank you! But I've made another improvement over your solution, simply to declare a HashMap<String, Boolean> and fill it with all the images from the phone as key and false as value (meaning they aren't processed). When I iterate the database of processed images, I set this boolean value to true, and then simply add to the final ArrayList the images (HashMap's keys) whose boolean value is true. Of course, I fix the ArrayList capacity so all insertions and lookups in the method are O(1)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to almost all sql (Sqlite, MySql, ....) speed issues is to create an index on the table.  See:  https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html
My guess your doing a full table scan on the imgFile you just added, that is as slow as it gets.

Other things you can do ( But won't help near as much as an index)
1)  Since you are not using the imgFile returned from Sqlite, change your sql to `'Select count() From  ... '` which will return an integer that is greater than zero if present.

2)  Add a limit clause to the select statement `"Select .... limit 1;"`  This will allow Sqlite to return once the first record is found.

Answer (score 0):

You already got the responses in form of the comments too!

First is the loop issue as how suggested e4c5. Of course that will make a huge boost.

The second is the `SELECT * FROM table` replace with `SELECT field1WhatIreallyNeed, field2WhatIreallyNeed FROM table`.

It helps adding to index the Where fields too.

I have integrated sqlite3 with NDK , so it is used C there and is even faster, but worth if your records are close to 1 million in 1 table.

The  best answer is in comment: you don't need database for this! And that would be the fastest. Think about the database how is read, where is stored? - in a file not, just with another constraints, parsing, processing overheads.

> I need the database, becuase my app overwrites the original photo, so
>   the photo always exists

No, you don't need database for this!

There are [eTags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag)

There is a meta file info

You can store in an separate file `downloaded_timestamp`, `processed_timestamp` and you can calculate if needs to be processed or not, and that will take milliseconds and not 10-20 seconds.

So, drop your database and use a simple file, read the data from that file all at once, not line by line.

Comment: So a file... I'm going to try it. But what about SharedPreferences? I mean, comverting the list to Json and getting it back?

Comment: SharedPreferences is an xml file... just look under the hoods always. Why don't like the simple things which runs faster: no xml parsing, validation overhead...since you are looking for speed, hence you must be closest to hardware as possible, the  to OS as possible and minimize the frameworks overheads.

Comment: So, do you suggest a simple text file with the path to every processed image in a líne, for example?

Comment: @fergaral text or even a binary file, witch has in each row: thePath, downloaded_timestamp, processed_timestamp

Comment: Etags are part of the HTTP specification and I don't quite see how it will help to search through files on the device. As for using a flat file to store the file names, flat files cannot be indexed and you will have to make n*(n/2) iterations through the file to find all the filenames that you need which will be much slower than a database

Comment: So, what do you then suggest?